# ubuntu-12.10-desktop "amd64" and "i386" .iso

Tags: installation, wubi, 64-bit, iso, 32-bit

Now when i tried to download Ubuntu for win7 installer, it gave me an iso with "amd64" in it, assuming that it's based on the processor, so i decided to check for any other downloads and found "i386", which i guess its for well, i3 processors, and decided to download it instead since i use i5, **but the question is: What is the difference between those two ISOs? and why should i install the amd64 version on my i5 laptop?**